# Coq: help to formalize an informal proof

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

```
Theorem ev_ev__ev_full : forall n m,
  even (n+m) <-> (even n <-> even m).
Proof.
  intros n m. split.
  - intros H. split.
    + intros H1. apply (ev_ev__ev n m H H1).
    + intros H1. rewrite plus_comm in H. apply (ev_ev__ev m n H H1).
  - intros H.
```

Output:

```
  n, m : nat
  H : even n <-> even m
  ============================
  even (n + m)
```

Now n can be either even or not even.

- if n is even, m is also even. Then by `ev_sum` theorem (n+m) is also even.
- if n is not even, it has the form (n' + 1), where n' is even. m is also not even, and has the form (m' + 1), where m' is even. So their sum is equal to:

  n + m = n' + 1 + m' + 1 => n + m = (n' + m') + 2.

even ((n' + m') + 2). After `apply ev_SS` we get even (n' + m'). As we know that n' is even and m' is even, we `apply ev_sum`. And this proves the theorem.

How to write this informal proof in coq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with these lemmas:

```
Theorem even_S (n : nat) : (~even n <-> even (S n)) /\ (even n <-> ~even (S n)). Admitted.
Theorem contra {A B : Prop} (prf : A -> B) : ~B -> ~A. Admitted.
```

`even_S` is proven with induction, and I think it's one of the examples of theorems where making the conclusion stronger than you might expect makes it easier to prove (dropping either side of the `/\` makes the remaining side difficult). `contra` is a `tauto`logy.

Knowing `even_S`, the decidability of `even n` follows straightforwardly from induction on `n`.

```
Theorem even_dec (n : nat) : {even n} + {~even n}. Admitted.
```

This is a decision procedure: `even_dec n` tells you whether `n` is `even` or not, depending on whether it returns the left or right alternative. `{ _ } + { _ }` is the notation for `sumbool`. It's basically like a `bool` (it's in `Set` and so can be destructed in computationally relevant contexts) except it also witnesses one of the two given `Prop`s depending on the alternative. In your proof, the first step is branching on this property:

```
    destruct (even_dec n) as [prf_n | prf_n].
```

If `even n`, the proof is trivial.

```
    + admit.
```

Otherwise, the contrapositive of the backwards implication tells us `~even m`. We can also eliminate the `not`s:

```
    + pose proof (contra (proj2 H) prf_n) as prf_m.
      apply even_S in prf_n.
      apply even_S in prf_m.
```

The rest of the proof (asserting that `n = S n'`, `m = S m'`, `even n'`, `even m'` and thus `even (n + m)`) follows with some work (with `inversion`).

```
      admit.
```

(I have filled in the `admit`s myself and this path *does* successfully lead to the proof, but just spilling all the answers is no fun :).)

Comment: I proved even_S and contra. Can you explain, how to prove even_dec? I don't know what to do.

Comment: It's very simple: the entire proof is `induction n as [ | n rec]. - repeat constructor. - destruct rec as [rec | rec]; [right | left]; apply even_S. + assumption. + inversion_clear 1 as [ | ? no]. contradiction.` You do induction on `n`. `0` is even, so you return the left alternative with the proof `even 0` in that case. For `S n`, take a look at whether `n` is even and return the opposite alternative. Then use `even_S` to actually "step" the `even`/`~even` proof that proves that the chosen alternative is correct.